# how do I get my partition to mount in the file manager?

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted

Below is the image of how my partition table looks like:

[image: screenshot]

As I'm fairly new to Ubuntu, can someone please tell me how do I get my 121Gb partition **(/dev/sdb2)** to appear in the file manager?

I can see it's not mounted at any point, so I thought I would try and mount it at /home through `gparted`, but I'm unable to unmount the said partition either, and I'm not even sure if that's the right thing to do here. That said, Can someone help me get this thing done? Many thanks

PS: the partition is formatted in ext4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More details would help. Work as user root.

```
[user]$  sudo su -
password for user:
[root]#
```

I assume you have just created this partition and then you formatted it with ext4.

IF this is the correct point of entry, you need to create a directory, mount the file system against this directory, and optionally add this to /etc/fstab to have the system mount this at every reboot.

- fdisk   -- creates partitions, skipped details here
- mkfs.ext4  -- formats the partition: shown below

  [root]# mkfs.ext4   [-L  DeviceLABELname] /dev/sdb2
  [.. lots of output truncated ..]

Connect the newly formatted partition to the file system:

```
[root]# mkdir /data ; mount /dev/sdb2 /data  ;  df -h /data
```

This should show the mounted file system information.

Create entry to reconnect this partition at every reboot
**NOTE**: if this is a USB device that will be removed and inserted,
do NOT perform these next steps. Instead, pull it out, push it
back in.

```
[root]# echo '/dev/sdb2 /data  ext4   defaults  1 2' >> /etc/fstab

[root]# umount /data ; mount -a    # disconnect, remount from /etc/fstab
```

FOR A USB DEVICE, suggestion add label to device, system will automatically
mount the device when it is inserted.

/dev/sdb2  implies there is another partition ahead of this one, such as
/dev/sdb1  which, if on a USB device, could be a different format.

```
[root]# mkfs.ext4   -L  BCK250GB  /dev/sdb2
```

This puts the label BCK250GB on this partition.

**NOTE ABOUT REMOVABLE MEDIA**
IF there are 2+ partitions, and the other one is already discovered,
then it will be mounted. Bring up the graphical file manager tool and
click on the funny triangle just left of the name to 'eject' the
device safely. This should be done FOR ALL USB PARTITIONS before you
remove the device.

[image]

Pull this USB device out and plug it back in ONLY IF all other partitions
have been 'ejected' (which means umounted in Linux/UNIX world).

This should force the local GRAPHICAL system to see the device.

IF THIS IS A SERVER version of Ubunbu with no graphical interface ..
.. the above is not quite right, you have to do all the manual
steps above and use the 'df' command to see if it is mounted or not.

Last thing, get out of ROOT LOGIN, do not work as root unless you
have to.

```
[root]# exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the extended partition. You can see the partition made in the extended partition (sda6). And you can use the swap partition made in the extended partition. Add up the size of sda6 and your swap and it equals the size of the extended partition (sda2).